# Is the use of cursor needed to achieve the following query?

Tags: mysql, database, cursor

Consider the database:

- A Company has zero or more Branch companies
- A Company has zero or more Emails
- A Branch has zero or more Emails

---

And consider the following instance of that database:

- 1 Company with 2 Branches
- The Company has 1 Email
- Each branch has 2 Emails

(5 Emails in total)

If you prefer, check the [graphical representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrvrY.png) of that instance.

---

### Query

I'd like to make a query (MySQL) that retrieves all e-mails related to a given company (5, in the example). I couldn't find a solution, so after a bit of googling I found out that there's a thing called [cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29).

---

### Question

- Is the use of cursor needed to achieve the query above? Would it be a good solution? What would be your solution to the query above?

(tables are defined below)

---

My idea was to retrieve all branches for a given company (that query I could make), but from there I don't know how to *iterate* through the branches (result of the query) and get all the e-mails.

---

### Tables definitions in MySQL

```
-- Database tables
CREATE TABLE `company` (

        `c_id`          INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `c_name`        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY (`c_name`),
        UNIQUE KEY `c_id` (`c_id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `branch` (

        `b_id`          INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `c_id`          INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `b_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY (`b_name`),
        UNIQUE KEY `b_id` (`b_id`),
        KEY `c_id` (`c_id`),

        CONSTRAINT `branch_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`)
                REFERENCES `company` (`c_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `email` (

        `e_id`          INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `e_addr`        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY (`e_addr`),
        UNIQUE KEY `e_id` (`e_id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `c_email` (

        `c_id`          INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `e_id`          INT(11) NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`,`e_id`),
        KEY `e_id` (`e_id`),

        CONSTRAINT `c_email_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`)
                REFERENCES `company` (`c_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE,

        CONSTRAINT `c_email_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`e_id`)
                REFERENCES `email` (`e_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `b_email` (

        `b_id`          INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `e_id`          INT(11) NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`,`e_id`),
        KEY `e_id` (`e_id`),

        CONSTRAINT `b_email_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`)
                REFERENCES `branch` (`b_id`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE,

        CONSTRAINT `b_email_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`e_id`)
                REFERENCES `email` (`e_id`)    
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


-- Example of query
-- Retrieving all e-mails of a given branch
SELECT e_addr
        FROM email      AS _em
        JOIN b_email    AS _be ON _be.e_id = _em.e_id
        JOIN branch     AS _br ON _br.b_id = _be.b_id
        WHERE b_name = @bra2;

-- How to retrieve all e-mails related to a given company
-- (e-mails from the company itself and also from all of its branches)?
-- ?
```

Comment: I'm not sure you have the logic right in separating the entries into company and branch tables. Further, you shouldn't be breaking the emails out into multiple tables.

Comment: Do you mean that you prefer having a single e-mail table containing all e-mails? That's how it's! The tables `c_email` and `b_email` just make the relationship between `Company`/`Branch` with the table `Email`.

If you want more info in my design, please check http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63790/conversion-of-simple-erd-to-table-is-the-solution-below-any-good and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64815/implementing-a-simple-erd-in-mysql-is-the-implementation-below-100-compliant-w

I don't know if I quite understood your comment (sorry if I didn't!)

Comment: You can streamline your design and lower your query complexity by establishing all entities as "companies", having a type field (which identifies it as a top-level company vs a branch), then just having `email` refer directly to the `c_id` column (which will then be unique per entity). The branch table can then simply house the parent-child relationship (no need to duplicate the name column)

Comment: @Noah That's a nice idea, it has never occurred to me. I will (try to) analyze the query complexity gains (as you can see, this is the first time I program SQL). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need a cursor for this.  You can do this with SQL -- much better than a cursor.  It is something like:

```
select *
from ((select ce.c_id, e.email
       from c_email ce join
            email e
            on e.e_id = ce.e_id
      ) union all
      (select b.c_id, e.email
       from branch b join
            b_email be
            on b.b_id = be.b_id join
            email e
            on be.e_id = e.e_id
      )
     ) e
where ce.c_id = X;
```

EDIT:

You can add `b_id` into the second subquery but not the first.  Perhaps you could do:

```
select *
from ((select ce.c_id, e.email, NULL as b_id
       from c_email ce join
            email e
            on e.e_id = ce.e_id
      ) union all
      (select b.c_id, e.email, b.b_id
       from branch b join
            b_email be
            on b.b_id = be.b_id join
            email e
            on be.e_id = e.e_id
      )
     ) e
where ce.c_id = X
order by c_id, b_id;
```

Comment: I swear, every time I pull up the MySQL question list, you're here, too

Comment: Here's your query with a small modification: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/e2yqXvf5) (addition of b_id column). I tried with no success to order by b_id: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Q5WfLH5R). How do I order it?

Comment: @feelthhis . . . You can't really order by `b_id`, because that information is not available for companies.  How would you handle them?

Comment: Your [query](http://pastebin.com/e2yqXvf5) (with the addition of b_id) returns a table with three columns (c_id, b_id when available, e_addr). I wanted to order that table by b_id, but as you pointed out I couldn't do it. So the only way to do it is by building a different query? (please bear with my lack of knowledge with SQL :)

Comment: Your edit worked! The key was the casting `as b_id`. (can I call it a [casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Explicit_type_conversion)? :) Thank you very much!

Comment: @feelthhis . . . You *can* call it "casting", but a better term is "aliasing".  `cast()` is used to change the type of a variable.

Comment: All right, you got it. My english is a bit bad (not native), sorry for that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff suppose one wants to search by c_name (instead of c_id). Using your query as model, I built the following: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1c7fffhZ). It works, but, if possible, I'd like to hear your opinion on it. Do you approve it? :)

Comment: @feelthhis . . . That looks right.  You seem to be catching on to the idea.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you that much, but what about this one: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/pNrP1HDZ)? I didn't know I could freely nest SELECT like that!

Comment: @feelthhis . . . Yes, that also works.  Really, you can just test the queries and see if they are producing the results you want.